# Creating link option in form and modifying it's url in form alter hook

Tags: forms, hooks, ajax

I'm searching to modify a node add form, so far i added a personal field "link" to display as a button to add another node type if the user wants to, that link has this code in `hook_form_alter`, im catching a value from another select earlier and passing that value to my route::

```
    $selected_advertiser = isset($form_state->getUserInput()['field_advertiser'])? $form_state->getUserInput()['field_advertiser'] : "0";
    $url = Url::fromRoute('product.product_form', ['advertiser' => $selected_advertiser]);
    $form['product_modal'] = [
        '#type' => 'link',
        '#name' => 'product_modal',
        '#title' => t('New Product'),
        '#url' => $url,
        '#attributes' => [
            'class' => [
                'use-ajax',
                'button',
            ],
            'data-dialog-type' => 'modal',
            'data-dialog-options' => '{"width":800, "height": 500}',
            'disable-refocus' => true,
            'style'=>'display: inline-block',
        ],
        "#weight" => 5,
    ];
```

`routing.yml`

```
  product.product_form:
  path: /product/product_form/{advertiser}
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\my_module\Controller\mycontrollerController::openModalProduct'
    _title: 'Popup for product form'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'administer site configuration'
```

so the first time this runs it sets the $selected_advertiser to "0" but next time is setting properly to whatever id i have selected from previous select option, but the route to the button is still matched as default value "0", my debugger is showing the correct new route with the correct new id but the form button is not, im guessing this has something to do with unstated changes in form or something like that?

Comment: Why not create a new selected_advertiser field and hide, then use the value of the field to modify the $URL?

Comment: @HodbaKhalaf i think i understand the idea, i think looks good, let me try that